# Is there any kind of idiots guide to deploying your ASP.NET MVC website in one click?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment

I'm about to begin building a website using the ASP.NET MVC framework and I'm trying to find a good solution to 1)Source Control Management and 2)Deployment.  For the SCM, I'm probably going to use SourceGear since it integrates into Visual Studio nicely, but for deployment, I don't even know where to start.  Up until know, most websites that I've built were very static and every time I had to update the site, I would use an FTP program and just drag and drop the files to the server.  But now that I'm going to be building a much more dynamic web application, this approach feels dangerous (which, oddly enough, is also my middle name).

Does there exist some kind of idiots guide or tutorial that explains a good way to deploy an update to your website?

Thanks so much in advance for all your help!

Comment: Regarding SCM, other source control solutions also integrate well (and are free). I like SVN, and use the Ankh plugin. 

For deployment, not an idiots guide, but hopefully useful:  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Source Control**

For source control, I like to use SubVersion at home. I would recommend using [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) to install the server - it's free and ridiculously easy to use.

On the client side of things, I use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) (for shell integration) and [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) (for Visual Studio integration). The small ammount of money for VisualSVN is well worth it, but there is a free open source equivilent [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/).

That's just what I use and there are many alternatives out there.

**Deployment**

I would definitely recommend using Microsoft Web Deploy.

Scott Gu just blogged today about it - [Automating Deploy with Microsoft Web Deploy](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/09/13/automating-deployment-with-microsoft-web-deploy.aspx). There there is also Scott Hanselman's guide - [Web Deployment Made Awesome: If You're Using XCopy, You're Doing It Wrong](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebDeploymentMadeAwesomeIfYoureUsingXCopyYoureDoingItWrong.aspx).

I recently came across a couple of posts by Jon Torresdal using Team Foundation Server (SCM), TeamCity (CI), and Web Deploy to implement a 'no-click' web deployment. They make for very interesting reading but they're definitely not what you'd consider *idiots guide* material.

- [No-Click Web Deployment – Part 1](http://blog.torresdal.net/2010/08/05/NoClickWebDeploymentPart1.aspx)
- [No-Click Web Deployment – Part 2 – Web Deploy (a.k.a. msdeploy)](http://blog.torresdal.net/2010/08/16/NoClickWebDeploymentPart2WebDeployAkaMsdeploy.aspx)

HTHs,
Charles

Comment: I use xcopy and though I'm happy with it I think I'll read those articles... it's never late to learn new tricks ;-)